# Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0 ( JTable Issue )

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jtable

I am using JTables with Spring / Ajax , the data is being returned from Spring and is visible in Firebug.

However when the JTable is getting painted , I am getting this error

```
Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row 0
```

I am not getting the root cause of the issue. Below is the code snippet

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({"aaData" : data,
                           "aoColumns": [
                                        { "sTitle": "Name" },
                                        { "sTitle": "Address" },
                                        { "sTitle": "Phone" },
                                        { "sTitle": "Email" },
                                        ]
                      });
```

Can anybody please help.

Thanks in advance , Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of issue found.

The reason due to which I was getting this error was because I was trying to send a JAVA STRING Array Object to Datatables, which expects a JSON array.

Hence due to the mismatch in the type of Object expected, I was getting the above mentioned error.

Resolved the issue , by converting the String array into a JSON Array like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject(Arr);
```

Comment: could you please more specific? It seems I have the same issue - data got as an object instead of an array - (but I don't understand this answer yet)

Comment: @HoàngLong 
The DataTables expects a JSON Array which enables it to paint the data.Now when we are passing the Object directly, DataTables is unable to decipher it and throws an error. So to overcome this we need to convert the Object to a JSON Array , which is what I have done in the last line.
Hope this answers your query, please let me know if you need any more information.